# rails-api and authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a problem with authenticating requests made to my Rails API

In my application controller I hvae the following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

  private

    def authenticate_user_from_token!
      Rails.logger.debug "Authenticating..." <---------- (1)
      authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        Rails.logger.debug "options: #{options.inspect}" <-----------------------(2)
        user_email = options[:user_email].presence
        user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

        if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, token)
          sign_in user, store: false
        end
      end
    end

end
```

But the problem is that while (1) gets executed and logged, (2) is never reached for some reason. Anyone have a clue as to why this is?

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `ApplicationController` needs:

```
include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
```